# How to prevent Vuejs from processing slot content when `v-if="false"`

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a component that displays "Loading" while some data is being downloaded, and display a `<slot>` when done.

This Loader component has this markup:

```
<div>
    <div v-if="!isLoaded">Loading...</div>
    <slot v-if="isLoaded"></slot>
</div>
```

`isLoaded` is passed in a prop.

The host component has this markup:

```
<div>
    <Loader v-bind:isLoaded="records != null">
        Downloaded {{ records.length }} records!
    </Loader>
</div>
```

When the data is downloaded, `records` is initialized as an array (i.e. with some data in it).

The above code throws console error, because Vuejs processes the `{{ records.length }}` part even though the `Loader` component doesn't actually render the `<slot>` (i.e. while `records` is still `null`, and so `records.length` fails).

If I wrap the data with a `v-if` then everything behaves correctly:

```
<div>
    <Loader v-bind:isLoaded="records != null">
        <div v-if="records != null">
            Downloaded {{ records.length }} records!
        </div>
    </Loader>
</div>
```

Is it possible to achieve this result without the additional `v-if`?

I'm using Vuejs 2, but if it's impossible in v2 but possible in v3 then I'd like to know.

Comment: It is not the `render` function that throws an error it is a compiler. In your case you are trying to read `.length` probably from `null` of `undefined` value. You need to keep additional `v-if`, or you can return the `.length` from the `computedProperty` and make this check there.

Comment: @AdamOrlov thanks. If the compiler knows to not compile when there's a `v-if` in a `div`, why can't it know to not compile when the `slot` is protected by a `v-if` inside `Loader`? As for your suggestion - that would add boilerplate, and I'm trying to avoid that...

Comment: Because Compiler running through your `ParentComponent` sees an error and throws it. You can't pass "bad" code to your `ChildComponent`.

Comment: @AdamOrlov it's not "bad" code... this may be how Vuejs behaves due to some design decision or limitation, but it IS an inconsistency. If a `<slot>` is not rendered because of a `v-if` then the compiler doesn't need to compile the HTML that would go in the `<slot>` until it actually needs to be rendered. Like it does in all other cases when some HTML is not rendered due to a `v-if`.

Comment: by "bad" I mean code that throws error. Look, you can always write to Evan You, or open an issue on GH. It is just how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The slot can have fallback content like :

```
<div>
    <slot>Loading...</slot>
</div>
```

in parent :

```
<div>
    <Loader v-bind:isLoaded="records != null">
        <div v-if="records">
            Downloaded {{ records.length }} records!
        </div>
    </Loader>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good tip, thanks. Still, is there a way to achieve this while keeping the check inside `Loader`? I prefer not to have this additional `<div>` (to reduce clutter and indentation, and also to possibly make `Loader` do more stuff in the future).

Comment: you're welcome, you could also do `<div v-if="!isLoaded">Loading...</div>
    <slot v-else></slot>` without adding the root div

Comment: you mean inside `Loader`? I'm not sure what difference it makes... I want to avoid the `<div v-if="records">` in the host component...

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim using this conditional slot approach, your slot loose binding. [See an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076389/vuejs-slot-loose-binding)